# Python code to click a button using css selectors

Tags: python, css-selectors

I am brand new to python and am trying to modify some existing code. I have a form with the following elements:

```
<div class="v-actions">
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
    <input type="button" value="Accept"/>
    <input type="button" value="Reject"/>
</div>
```

If it exists, I want to click the `Accept` button. If not, I want to log that it is not found. Currently, the code is this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
import getpass
from gmail import Gmail
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from time import sleep

....

self.chrome_session = webdriver.Chrome()

....

links = self.chrome_session.find_elements_by_class_name('link-record')
links = [(link.text, link.get_attribute('href').decode('utf-8'))
         for link in links]
if len(links) == 0:
    print("No work orders available at {0}".format(
        datetime.datetime.now()))
else:
    for link_text, link_url in links:
        print("Clicking work order {0}".format(link_text))
        self.chrome_session.get(link_url)
        potential_input = self.chrome_session.find_element_by_class_name('v-actions').find_element_by_tag_name('input');
        if potential_input.get_attribute('value') == 'Accept':
            potential_input.click()
            print("Accepted work order {0} at {1}.".format(link_text,datetime.datetime.now()))
        else:
            print("Accept input not found.")
....
```

In jquery, the selector would be something like:

```
div.v-actions input[value=Accept]
```

I am not sure how to do this with Python. I would rather not loop through all the inputs. I just want to find if the specific input exists and accept it if it does.

How do I translate the css selector to Python?

**UPDATE**

I am trying this now:

```
potential_input = self.chrome_session.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='v-actions']/input[@value='Accept']")
if potential_input.is_displayed():
    print("Accept input not found")
else:
    potential_input.click()
    print("Accepted work order {0} at {1}.".format(link_text,
                                                   datetime.datetime.now()))
```

I am not sure how to test if it found the element. I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"81","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:49795","User-Agent":"Python http auth"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"sessionId\": \"7b58b250-ca34-11e7-967d-6fd95b435952\", \"id\": \":wdc:1510771259080\"}","url":"/click","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"click","directory":"/","path":"/click","relative":"/click","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/click","queryKey":{},"chunks":["click"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/7b58b250-ca34-11e7-967d-6fd95b435952/element/:wdc:1510771259080/click"}}
```

I am not sure if my selector is wrong, or if my test to see if it was found is bad.

**UPDATE 2**

I have modified the code to the following:

```
for link_text, link_url in links:
    print("Clicking work order {0}".format(link_text))
    self.chrome_session.get(link_url)
    try:
        self.chrome_session.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Accept']").click()
        print("Accepted work order {0} at {1}.".format(link_text,datetime.datetime.now()))
    except ElementNotVisibleException:
        print("Accept input not found")
self.chrome_session.back()
```

Now the code executes, and it acts like it worked (it prints `Accepted work order {0}`), but it didn't correctly fire the `.click()` because the record still exists in the list. But, if I manually click accept, it correctly processes the job.

Is my selector still wrong? Or, is the click function incorrectly applied?

Comment: Can we get the full code? What libraries are you using? What is `self.chrome_session`?

Comment: I am not able to provide the full code, but I have provided the libraries and the definition of the chrome_session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use XPath to select your input and be pythonic by asking for forgiveness if you try to select something that is not there/visible:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException

try:
    potential_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='v-actions']/input[@value='Accept']")
    print("Input found!")
    potential_input.click()
    print("Input clicked!")
except ElementNotVisibleException:
    # Asked for forgiveness for
    # attempting to select element
    # that isn't there/visible
    print("Input not there!")
```

Sourced from Selenium [XPath](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath) and [Exceptions](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=exception#selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException) docs.

Comment: I think I am making progress. The selector is wrong because it throws the `ElementNotVisibleException` even though I know the element is there.